# Pull Numeric characters and add spacing from DataTable JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a `DataTable` which is doing a `GET` and populates, The data returned only has one option returned called which is a tel number but the tel num returned has 'test-' in front of it (e.g. test-010101010101).

What i want is to remove the 'test-' and then add spaces after every 4 digits (e.g. 0101 0101 0101.

I have tried the below but cant get it working

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    $('#dialPlanListDataTable').DataTable().rows().eq(0).each(function (index) {
         var row = $('#dialPlanListDataTable').DataTable().row(index);
         var data = row.data();
         console.log(data)
         var sd = data.text();  
         sd = parseInt(sd);
         console.log(sd)
        });
},
```

This results in

[image]

Comment: Why the double naming? `function (row, data` but then you do `var row =` and `var data =`

Comment: You can add the spaces every 4 characters by following this logic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/519413) and changing `","` to `" "` and `{3}` to `{4}`. Removing the `test-` is a simple `replace()` operation

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Doesnt work with the `DataTable` or i am doing something wrong.  Completely new to `DataTables` though

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - Your comment is not relevant to the question being asked.  I understand what your saying but it makes no heads or tails

Comment: The logic to update the format works, https://jsfiddle.net/bo782vkc/, so you need to debug the Datatables logic. I would suggest using `render` on the cell individually instead: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with the following:

```
var strippedTelNo = '';

"columns": [
    {   "data": null,
        "render": function(data) {
                strippedTelNo = data.telNumber
                                    .replace(/[A-Z, a-z]|-/g, '')
                                    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{4})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

            return strippedTelNo
        }
    }...
```

Comment: Doing regex replace twice against each target cell could be the issue from performance standpoint. Please, checkout my updated answer.